# Multiple sliding panels in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

fairly new to Javascript and JQuery, so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge. That being said, I am trying to make a page with a navigation menu to multiple topics and subtopics. When a user clicks a topic, I want to have a sliding drop-down list display subpages. I have the slider working fine, but when I click to slide, all of the menus slide. I know that this is because they all have the same class, so I am trying to find a way to further identify the slide I want to click on. I would rather keep them all the same class, for the sake of CSS design. The only other option I can think of doing is to write out Jquery for each individual ID. I can do that, but it would be rather time consuming, so I am hoping to find a way around that. Anyone know what I can do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").click(function(){
        $(".sub").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<ul class="sidenav">
<li><img src="images/list_plus.png" width="25px" height="25px" class="main" id="intro" /><a href="index.php">Introduction</a>
    <ul class="sub" id="intro">
        <li>Purpose</li>
        <li>Such and such blah blah.</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><img src="images/list_plus.png" width="25px" height="25px" class="main" id="geo" /><a href="geography.php">Geography</a>
    <ul class="sub" id="geo">
    <li>What it is</li>
    <li>How it is has changed</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to slide the `sub` element within the same `li`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find('.sub').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MdCj8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().children('.sub').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

`e.currentTarget` will refer the element you clicked and it will search for the associated `.sub`.

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rBUDa/